# how to encrypt and save the file on firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Any method or function that encrypt the files (media or another) and save on firebase storage after that decrypt the file on fetching and show the original file to the user.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you want to encrypt file for single user? Or by encryption you want that only uploading user can view it ?

Comment: If you're worried about data encryption on backend side, I suggest you to take a look at [the firebase privacy and security page][1] and to [this statement][2] by Virgil Security about Firebase's E2EE.


  [1]: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/
  [2]: https://virgilsecurity.com/announcing-firebase-sdk/

Comment: @UmarHussain yes only for single user. yes only uploading user can view if anyone access the storage he found encrypted files !

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to restrict file access to other users you can use security rules on firbease storage (e.g. folder name can be equal to firbease user's uid and only that user can access it.). But remember that data is not actually encrypted Firebase project admins have full access to the storage and can view any file without any restrictions.

If you want to upload file only after encryption you have to look for Android OS encryption support. You will find many libraries to do this on device and then simply upload the encrypted file. You have to manage the encryption keys in cloud most likely with Firestore or realtime database. Limitations in this case will include file size and complexity of encryption.

Comment: yes i defined the firebase storage rules according to your first paragraph basically your second paragraph is main point. Thanks for your point.Let you know.